# Unable to call AppDelegate openURL( ) while using the Dropbox SDK

Tags: swift, dropbox-api, openurl

I'm trying to add Dropbox authentication to my app, but it's showing me this error:

```
DropboxSDK: app delegate does not implement application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:
```

Below is the code in my app delegate:

```
let dbSession = DBSession(appKey: dbAppKey, appSecret: dbAppSecret, root: kDBRootDropbox)
DBSession.setSharedSession(dbSession)

func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {

    if DBChooser.defaultChooser().handleOpenURL(url){
        return true
    }
    else if DBSession.sharedSession().handleOpenURL(url){

        if DBSession.sharedSession().isLinked(){
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

I had created an NSObject for authentication and handling other operations related to Dropbox API. Below is my authentication code:

```
if !DBSession.sharedSession().isLinked(){
    DBSession.sharedSession().linkFromController(viewController)
}
else{
    delegate.authenticationStatus!(true, error: nil)
}
```

I'm getting this error after it's successfully logged in. I had also set LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in my plist and also added the URL types. I'm unable to find where I'm making a mistake.

Also I'm trying to check if Dropbox app is present or not using

```
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "dbapi-1://")!){
}
```

But it's giving me below error:

```
canOpenURL: failed for URL: "dbapi-1://" - error: "(null)"
canOpenURL: failed for URL: "dbapi-2://1/connect" - error: "(null)"
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: iOS 9 requires you to add the URL schemes you are going to use in the app in the app's plist, and this post tells you what to add: https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/08/important-update-your-core-api-app-for-ios-9/

Comment: are you running the code on a device that has the dropbox app installed?

Comment: Can you share your implementation of `application:openURL`? The error seems to indicate that it's missing.

Comment: @cezheng No. App is not installed on my device

Comment: then install the app and try again

Comment: @AnkitaShah That code looks *slightly* wrong, in that you're not returning true unless the linking was successful, but I wouldn't expect that to cause the error you see. Could you clarify exactly when you see that error message?

Comment: @cezheng But it should allow to work without app too. I want that user should be allowed login without app too.

Comment: @smarx Once I'm done with successful login. The Dropbox login screen is dismissed and I'm back to my app, but application:openURL is not called and it give me this error

Comment: You have to understand that these url schmes belongs to the dropbox app and are used to communicate with the dropbox app. I surely believe that the sdk should have some functions that do not require the dropbox app, but not these url schmes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app delegate appears to implement a different `openURL` signature than what the SDK expects.

Change the signature to this instead:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL,
    sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
```

Do take note that this method has been marked `deprecated` in the iOS 9 SDK.  It will continue to work as expected for a while though.

Comment: Yes. It's working now. Thanks a lot. Also, what are this error like canOpenURL: failed for URL: "dbapi-1://" - error: "(null)"
canOpenURL: failed for URL: "dbapi-2://1/connect" - error: "(null)"

Comment: I believe that's just the log message that appears when `canOpenURL` returns false (in this case, when the Dropbox app is not installed).

Answer (score 1):

From or after iOS 13 adding the following func to SceneDelegate.swift seems to work:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    if let url = URLContexts.first?.url {
        print(url)
        
        if let authResult = DropboxClientsManager.handleRedirectURL(url) {
            switch authResult {
            case .success:
                print("Success! User is logged into Dropbox.")
            case .cancel:
                print("Authorization flow was manually canceled by user!")
            case .error(_, let description):
                print("Error: \(description)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```